# How can I get <textarea> value in parent component from child?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The aim of my application is to get some array of messages(mes) from api-url and send answer(subFunction method) for every message. After that message will be delete from 'mes' array. 'Message' is a parent component responsible for fetch data(componentDidMount event) and rendering message through map method. 'MessageItem' responsible for get value from 'textarea' - the body of answer. But I can't transfer this.state.value(textarea.value) from from MessageItem to parent component. If I place 'subFunction' in child component, I can't change this.state.mes

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const url="api-url";

class MessageItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         value:'',
      };
    };

 handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     }
render() {
return (
  <div className="message_wrap" key={this.props.message_id}>
                                <div className="message_body">
                                       {this.props.message_body}
                                </div>            
                                 <div className="input-field col s12">
                                     <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                                     <label htmlFor="textarea1">
                                         Ответ
                                     </label>
                                <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                                    Отправить
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    );
  }
}
class Message extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         mes:[],
      };
    };
   componentDidMount(){
    fetch(url).then(function(response){
        return response
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then((data)=>{
        this.setState({mes:data})
    })
    }
    subFunction(user_id, value) {
   /*This method have to send answer with user id and textarea value*/
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.mes.map((index)=>
                (
                    <MesItem
                             key={index.message_id}
                             message_body={index.message_body}
                             onClick={this.subFunction.bind(this, index.user_id)}
                    />

                )
          )
            }
        </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Message/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `function` from parent component to child, call that function to pass the value from child to parent.

Like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.value)}>
     Отправить
</button>
```

Now do `console.log` inside `subFunction` it will print proper value:

```
subFunction(user_id, value) {
   console.log(user_id, value)
}
```

Comment: I can't understand how I have to pass this.state.value in onClick={this.subFunction.bind(this, index.user_id)} of parent component

Comment: Awesome! It's work! Could you explain me how?  I would be very thankful to you!

Comment: reason is, in each onclick function your are binding user_id, and value you are passing from child component so each time when that function will get called it will get 2 parameters, user_id and value, `this.props.onClick(this.state.value)` will basically call the parent function and it will pass the value of input field :)

Answer (score -1):

Assign a `ref` to the `textarea` in the child component and to the `MesItem` and then you can fetch the value like

```
class MessageItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         value:'',
      };
      mesItem = [];
    };

 handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     }
render() {
return (
  <div className="message_wrap" key={this.props.message_id}>
                                <div className="message_body">
                                       {this.props.message_body}
                                </div>            
                                 <div className="input-field col s12">
                                     <textarea value={this.state.value} ref={(ta) => {this.text = ta}}onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                                     <label htmlFor="textarea1">
                                         Ответ
                                     </label>
                                <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                                    Отправить
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    );
  }
}
class Message extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         mes:[],
      };
    };
   componentDidMount(){
    fetch(url).then(function(response){
        return response
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then((data)=>{
        this.setState({mes:data})
    })
    }
    subFunction(user_id, i) {
           console.log(this.mesItem[i].text.value)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.mes.map((index, i)=>
                (
                    <MesItem
                             ref = {(ip) => {this.mesItem[i] = ip}}
                             key={index.message_id}
                             message_body={index.message_body}
                             onClick={this.subFunction.bind(this, index.user_id , i)}
                    />

                )
          )
            }
        </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Message/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined  ref: ip => { this.mesItem[i] = ip;

Comment: Initialise mesItem

Comment: I think, as i see in [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in 'MessItem' it must be ref={this.props.inputRef} and in parent: inputrRef = {(ip) => {this.mesItem[i] = ip}}. But i have the same problem with undefined value..